Bound for the values of a polynomial on [0,1] in term of the partial sum of its coefficients.
I encountered the following nice little fact in a little problem of mine, and would like to know  what proofs you could have in mind !
Consider $a_0, \ldots, a_n$ $n$ real numbers and form the polynomial:
$$P(x) =\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i.$$
Prove that one has the following bound on the value of the polynomial: $$\forall x \in [0,1], \min\{ \sum_{0 \leq i \leq j} a_i, j =0 \ldots n\}  \leq P(x) \leq \max\{ \sum_{0 \leq i \leq j} a_i, j =0 \ldots n\}.$$
The question is for instance a useful addition to :
How to obtain uniform bounds on a polynomial by looking at its coefficients.

Let $q_j=\sum_{0 \leq k \leq j} a_k, j=0,..n$ and note that $P(0)=q_0, P(1)=q_n$ so to prove the inequality in the OP we can assume $x \in (0,1)$. Let $q,Q$ the min and max in cause so $q \le q_k \le Q, k=0,...n$
Now we note that $\frac{P(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{k=0}^nq_kx^k+\sum_{k \ge n+1}q_nx^k, 0<x<1$
In particular since $q \le q_k \le Q$ we have $$\frac{q}{1-x} \le \sum_{k=0}^nq_kx^k+\sum_{k \ge n+1}q_nx^k \le \frac{Q}{1-x}$$ hence $$\frac{q}{1-x} \le \frac{P(x)}{1-x} \le \frac{Q}{1-x}$$
Since $x \in (0,1)$ the required inequality $q \le P(x) \le Q$ follows.

Let $x$ be a variable over $[0,1]$, let $z$ be an indeterminate and let $\pi_{j}(\varphi)$ denote the coefficient of $z^j$ in a given polynomial $\varphi(z)\in\Bbb{R}[z]$. Moreso, let $\varphi_{\text{min}},\varphi_{\text{max}}$, respectively denote the minimum value and maximum value obtained by the polynomial function $\varphi:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ determined by $\varphi(z)$. Finally, $$\Sigma_{\text{min}}(\varphi(z)):=\min\{\sum_{0\leq{i}\leq{j}}\pi_{i}(\varphi):j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}\}$$
$$\Sigma_{\text{max}}(\varphi(z)):=\max\{\sum_{0\leq{i}\leq{j}}\pi_{i}(\varphi):j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}\}$$
Noticeably, for each $c\in\Bbb{R}$ there is the following :
$$(\mathbf{I})\;\;\Sigma_{\text{min}}(c+\varphi(z))=c+\Sigma_{\text{min}}(\varphi(z))\;;\Sigma_{\text{max}}(c+\varphi(z))=c+\Sigma_{\text{max}}(\varphi(z))$$
$$(\mathbf{II})\;\;\Sigma_{\text{min}}(-\varphi(z))=-\Sigma_{\text{max}}(\varphi(z))$$
$$(\mathbf{III})\;\;\Sigma_{\text{min}}(z\cdot\varphi(z))=\min(\{0,\Sigma_{\text{min}}(\varphi(z))\})\;;\Sigma_{\text{max}}(z\cdot\varphi(z))=\max(\{0,\Sigma_{\text{max}}(\varphi(z))\})$$
Now, prove the posted claim by contradiction and assume $\mathcal{S}:=\{\varphi(z)\in\Bbb{R}[z]:\mathbf{E}_{\varphi}\}\neq\emptyset$ where $$\mathbf{E}_{\varphi}:\varphi_{\text{min}}<\Sigma_{\text{min}}(\varphi)\lor\Sigma_{\text{max}}(\varphi)<\varphi_{\text{max}}$$
Since $\mathbf{E}_{\varphi(z)}$ is obviously false whenever $\varphi(z)$ is a constant polynomial then by $\mathbf{(I),(II),(III)}$ we may choose of the $\mathcal S$ elements of minimum degree a non-constant polynomial $P(z)\in\mathcal{S}$ such that $P(0)=0$ but then $\mathbf{(III)}$ guarantees $\frac{P(z)}{z}\in\mathcal{S}$ which violates the minimality of $\deg(P(z))$. Reductio ad absurdum.

Thank you all for nice answers ! I wanted to share a last answer by induction.
The property clearly holds for $n=0$ (and $n=1$), so we explain the basis of the induction argument.
$a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_n$ being given, call
$$ \alpha_i=\min\{\sum_{\ell=i}^j a_{\ell}, j =i \ldots n\} \text{ and } \beta_i=\max\{\sum_{\ell=i}^j a_{\ell}, j =i \ldots n\}$$
and observe that, by definition,
$$\alpha_0 = \min\{a_0,  a_0+ \alpha_1\} \text{ and } \beta_0 = \max\{a_0, a_0+ \beta_1\}$$
Then assume that for $x \in [0,1]$,
$$\alpha_1 \leq a_1 + a_2 x + \ldots + a_n x^{n-1} \leq \beta_1$$
holds then, distinguishing the cases acccording to the sign of $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$,
$$ \min\{a_0, a_0+ \alpha_1\} \leq a_0 + x(a_1 + a_2 x + \ldots + a_n x^{n-1})  \leq \max\{a_0, a_0+ \beta_1\}$$
which gives the induction by our previous observation.
